# How can I filter out certain appointments in Outlook macros?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have too many meetings at work, so I thought I might use an Outlook VBA macro to block my calendar when I have too many meetings, so I can use the rest of the time to actually get things done.

```
`Sub BlockMoreCalendarAppts()
 
Dim myAcct As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myFB As String
Dim tDate As Date
Dim d As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim test As String
Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem

' it needs to know whose FB to check
Set myAcct = Session.CreateRecipient("name.lastname@domain.com")

' days to check
For d = 0 To 5
tDate = Date + d

' use start of working day or there about
' false counts tenetive and oof as busy
myFB = myAcct.FreeBusy(tDate + #9:30:00 AM#, 5, False)

' this gets the # of 5 min periods before the start time
i = (TimeValue(tDate + #9:30:00 AM#) * 288)

' only count free busy for 7:10 hours from start + at least 1 additional 5 min period
' # of min in working day / 5
' skips busy times in the evening
test = Mid(myFB, i, 435 / 5)

CountOccurrences = UBound(Split(test, "1")) ' busy, oof or tentative
  ' theoretical WHERE statement goes here?
    

CountO = UBound(Split(test, "0")) ' free

'round to hours for subject
times = Round(((CountOccurrences * 5) / 60), 2)

' create all day busy event
' there are 12 5 minute periods per hour
' 60 = 5 hours
If CountOccurrences >= 60 Then

' default calendar

Set oAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
With oAppt
    .Subject = times & " hours of appt today"
    .Start = tDate
    .ReminderSet = False
    .Categories = "Full Day"
    .AllDayEvent = True
    .BusyStatus = olBusy
    .Save
End With

End If

' check next day
Next d

End Sub`
```

The logic is that if I have more than 5 hours of meetings in a day, it sets an all day appointment and marks me as busy.

I tested the attached macro, which works, but, I want to filter out appointments which contain certain words in the subject. For example, "Lunch" or "Focus". In other words, I don't want "Lunch" to be counted in my five hours of meetings.

I have not figured out how to use a WHERE function to filter particular appointments for that day. Any help would be appreciated.

This is based (heavily) on the great work of Diane Poremsky at https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/limit-number-appointments-day/

Comment: Curious as to why you'd wish to exclude "lunch" since you (hopefully) wouldn't be counting that towards productive time.

Comment: In addition to lunch, I also sometimes have a focus blocker or similar. I don't want to count these, when counting how many hours of meetings I have. So, if I have 4.5 hours of meetings, lunch should not then block the entire day from additional meetings - in reality I can still "take" another 30 minutes.  Same with the focus blockers; the point of this macro is block the rest of the day for getting things done, so if I have previously blocked two hours to have them free from meetings, the macro does not need to incorporate those two hours into my five hour maximum of meetings.

Comment: I get that you're trying to stop _all_ your productive time being blocked out but I don't really get why you wish to exclude, i.e., count as productive, lunch. Neither here nor there. I think the answer I provided should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to looping through appointments then you could add them all up like that? Pseudocode:

```vb
' Set the start and end times for the day
Dim startTime As Date
startTime = DateSerial(year, month, day) + TimeValue("9:00 AM")
Dim endTime As Date
endTime = DateSerial(year, month, day) + TimeValue("5:00 PM")

' Set the search criteria for the appointments
Dim filter As String
filter = "[Start] >= '" & startTime & "' AND [End] <= '" & endTime & "'" & _
        "AND [Subject] NOT Like '*focus*'"

' Get the calendar folder for the default account
Dim calendarFolder As Folder
Set calendarFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

' Set the current appointment to the first appointment of the day
Dim currentAppointment As AppointmentItem
Set currentAppointment = calendarFolder.Items.Find(filter)

' Loop through all appointments on the day
Do While Not (currentAppointment Is Nothing)
    ' Process the current appointment
    ' ...
    
    ' Get the next appointment
    Set currentAppointment = calendarFolder.Items.FindNext
Loop
```